# New-PSSession - WinRM cannot process the request

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list all the websites in IIS on a remote server using PowerShell scripting. Below is how I am trying to connect to the server:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server
```

But when I run the script I am getting the following error:

```
New-PSSession : [Server] Connecting to remote server Server failed with the
following error message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error
occurred while using Kerberos authentication: Cannot find the computer Server.
Verify that the computer exists on the network and that the name provided is
spelled correctly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
Help topic.
At C:\AppServers\Application.ps1:8 char:8
+         $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

The server is already enabled to receive remote requests.

> Update:

Below is the full function that i am trying to run:

```
function audit-servers {  
if (Test-path "ApplicationsOnTheServer.txt") {Remove-Item "ApplicationsOnTheServer.txt"}
if (Test-Path "ServersList.txt") {
foreach ($server in Get-Content .\ServersList.txt) {

    "Application Server : $server`n" | out-file -FilePath "ApplicationsOnTheServer.txt" -Append
    "Applications list:" | out-file -FilePath "ApplicationsOnTheServer.txt" -Append
    $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential domainabc\myname
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Import-Module WebAdministration;Get-iissite} | out-file -FilePath "ApplicationsOnTheServer.txt" -Append
}
} else {
    "ServersList.txt file is missing"
     break;
}
"`nAll Done!`n"}
```

The ServersList.txt has atstappvmabc.tsteag.com

Comment: Try to pass the `Credential` parameter along with a domain user to `New-PSSession`.  Passing Credentials (even if basically using the same user) might resolve the Kerberos issue.

Comment: Error message clearly stated that you passed `Server` instead of `$Server` to `-ComputerName` which is incorrect unless the name of your server is literally `Server`. If after correcting that you still receives an error, it will be different than what you pasted in your question.

Comment: I tried Credential parameter and tried with domain name as well with no success.

Answer (score 2):

The error message clearly states that you wanted to connect to the server named `Server` not to the server which name is stored in `$Server` variable (text in bold is actually the name of the server you try to connect to):

> New-PSSession : [**Server**] Connecting to remote server **Server** failed

If you tried to connect to the server named for example `MyServer01.example.com` you'd receive the error like below (truncated):

```
PS C:\> New-PSSession -ComputerName "MyServer01.example.com"
```

> New-PSSession : [**MyServer01.example.com**] Connecting to remote server **MyServer01.example.com** failed (...)

Even though you state that you try to execute

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Server
```

You actually execute (notice missing dollar sign)

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName Server
```

The above was also taken from the error message you pasted. I'd suggest to first skip the variable and try to enter server path in the command itself to verify it's working:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "MyServer01.example.com"
```

And then, if it works, put the path in variable and test again.

Comment: After typing up the same thing and thinking, wait a minute, my assumption was that the server name was redacted from the error message. If it's actually a typo in the way you describe I'll buy you a sandwich and learn to trust my instincts more.

Comment: $Server gets assigned a server name while executing the function. i have tried with domain name and without. Same results. i have used the Credential parameter too with no luck. Test-Connection works perfectly for the same server.

Comment: Please add the information about the current code ([mcve]) and what error you receive. Currently I don't have any info to reproduce your error. And make sure that you don't forget the dollar sign, please.

Comment: I have updated the question with full function i am using.

Comment: But you still haven't updated the question with what error you receive and the code you use doesn't contain `Test-Connection` part you mentioned to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving `FullyQualifiedErrorId : NetworkPathNotFound` generally means that the name you're passing to the `-ComputerName` parameter can't be resolved.

Perhaps try running `Test-Connection $Server` to troubleshoot what's happening there.

Comment: "Test-Connection $Server" works fine but new session does not

Answer (score 0):

Your variable $Server contains wrong value. You have to assign valid computer name to $Server.